# how to create Dynamic Input value with two different datatype time and text and insert into one single column

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, dynamic

I have **Dynamic Input box** with **Time Input** and **Text Input** I want to show as a **list items** and also wanted to insert values in **one column** of table in SQL

example :

- 09.30 PM   Saturday night journey begins.
- 01.30 AM   We Reach the Base village
- 02:00 AM   Some Yumm, Breakfast!

> How to add multiple input for list item with two different datatype time and text ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting into complex code, make two different Varible/text Input/columns

if you still want use them add something in between and use Sting function like : strlen() / stripos() / stristr() ---- and while using it in code make two different variables

example value [startTime09.30 PM - ReachTime 10.00AM]

Get Lenth of Text strlen() [44Charecters] >> find position of "-" stripos("-")[23rd postion] >> Chop strings left part and store it in variable do same with remaining